# Best way to process the records in After Update triggers - Sets or Lists

Tags: update, after-trigger, trigger, recursion

This may be a very primitive question but am failing to choose the best way and am trying to follow the best practices. We have many Salesforce Apps implemented, as a result there are many record types. I am writing an AfterUpdate trigger which should process if the record's recordtypeId is x and status field is Submitted. I have 2 ways to do this.
First way is using set:

```
set<Id> customObjIds = new set<Id>();
for(customObj c: trigger.new){
if(c.recordtypeId == 'x' && ((StatusOldValue != StatusNewValue) && Status ='Submitted'){
customObjIds.add(c.ID);}//if loop 
}//for loop

Then query all the customObjIds record data (again) and perform the logic.
```

Second way is without sets:

```
for(customObj c: trigger.new){
    if(c.recordtypeId == 'x' && ((StatusOldValue != StatusNewValue) && Status ='Submitted'){
//Perform the logic
}//for loop
```

The first way eliminates any duplicates. Other than this do the above 2 codes make any difference in their execution? Which one do you suggest?

Also, I am trying to insert few tasks in after update trigger? Does it really require a Recursive check?

Answer (score 3):

The general rule of thumb is that if you can't have duplicates, don't use a Set. The correct form in your case would be to use a List, instead:

```
list<Id> customObjIds = new list<Id>();
for(customObj c: trigger.new){
if(c.recordtypeId == 'x' && ((StatusOldValue != StatusNewValue) && Status ='Submitted'){
customObjIds.add(c.ID);}//if loop 
}//for loop

Then query all the customObjIds record data (again) and perform the logic.
```

Basically, it comes down to using common sense. Every record in the list will have a unique ID in this case. However, if you were using Account records:

```
set<Id> accountIds = new set<Id>();
for(customObj c: trigger.new){
if(c.recordtypeId == 'x' && ((StatusOldValue != StatusNewValue) && Status ='Submitted'){
customObjIds.add(c.Account__c);}//if loop 
}//for loop

Then query all the customObjIds record data (again) and perform the logic.
```

Although I would argue that any performance gain would be insignificant at best; using either Set or List would be okay here (filters don't care if the same ID appears more than once).

The important part is that you should almost always use a List or Set, and process the records only after going through the initial process of checking the records.

I refer to this as the Aggregate-Query-Update pattern, where you first gather all the necessary values you need, perform a query as necessary, and then perform an update on all the records gathered from the first part.

This is also generally mentioned in the ["Best Practice: Bulkify Your Code"](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code) blog post.

Comment: Curious to know why you say "if you can't have duplicates, don't use a Set". I prefer to use a Set in this case because it **shows** there are no duplicates without having to mentally work back through the code and convince myself that no duplicates are possible. I guess it cost a bit more CPU effort, but I prefer the clarity of the type telling me extra information about the code. Your thoughts?

Comment: @Aidan Most of the time, it doesn't matter if there are duplicates; I would suggest that using List is more frequently the correct solution than not *because* of the better storage speed characteristics. The only reason to use a Set is if you later want to check if a value is contained in the Set (and then, List.indexOf can provide feature parity here). If you don't want to mentally work out if there are duplicates, just go with a List all the time, unless you're *specifically* looking for duplicates; your CPU time will thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I still prefer types to tell me as much as possible, so I'll probably continue to use Set unless performance turns out to be a problem. But really useful to know your thinking on it.

Comment: @Aidan Yeah, it's not worth losing sleep over. There's so many better optimizations you can worry about than List/Set. I usually go with whatever I'm using for my other variables so I can combine variable declarations for performance reasons.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Thanks for the feedback. However, you stated that second way of doing will run into errors "The second, however, almost certainly will run in to problems." Could I please know what sort of errors?

Comment: @Kanikala Putting DML or queries in a loop will lead to governor limits being hit on large data volumes (~100-150 records). The only time you should allow yourself to do the logic directly (your second code block in question) is when there are no queries or DML statements being used. This is pretty rare in practice, though it's likely you'll run into an appropriate situation sooner or later.

Comment: @sfdcfox: I am just inserting tasks here in the logic for which I am making use of Lists to collect and insert them at once after the loop. And no queries, just browsing trigger.new recs.  Thanks so much for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

You can directly work with the records after they fulfill the conditions, which means you can go with the 2nd way of the code.

The first way with the Sets is wrong because you are adding extra processing time by querying the records again and potentially hitting the *100 Limit of SOQL queries*, which we see a lot, especially on triggers (check other peoples questions here).

After conditions are fulfilled, you can create a custom method to perform the logic you need, so in that way the code is more clean/readable. Like below:

```
for(customObj c: trigger.new){
    if(c.recordtypeId == 'x' && ((StatusOldValue != StatusNewValue) && Status ='Submitted'){
        //method to perform the logic
        doTheLogic();
    }
}
```

On the last point, on inserting tasks in after update trigger, it may be a problem of Recursion if **you are already** in Task trigger and you have added logic on before/after insert on Task trigger.

Also keep in mind that you should collect in a `List<Task> taskList` the Task records that you want to insert, and insert the list (`taskList`) in the end of all trigger methods.

Comment: In many cases you'll want, in that `if`, to accumulate matching records in a new `List<sObject>` and pass that list to `doTheLogic()`. Otherwise you run the risk of a non-bulkifiable design.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct, or, at best, is misleading. Adding values to a Set doesn't use a SOQL query, so there wouldn't be a problem with the first example. The second, however, almost certainly will run in to problems.

Comment: The first example on the question of using Sets, is mentioned also the line:  `Then query all the customObjIds record data (again) and perform the logic.`, which is redudant I think (as I have answered), while in the second example that line is not included and would be the correct way, because why would be needed to query the records again to perform the logic? Hope to be clear

Comment: @EnrikHysko Thanks for your valuable time. Cheers!